# UpdateFrame on multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, flicker, brain-computer-interface

I have made a Brain-Computer-Interface (BCI) in C#, there are flickering `pictureboxes` on each of the forms. However, it is only in the main form where the flickering occurs. Does any one know how to get the `updateframe` to work on the other forms as well?

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DTU_BCI_SPELLER_BioRadio_Interface
{
    static class Program
    {
               [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct Message
        {
            public IntPtr hWnd;
            public int msg;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public uint time;
            public Point p;
        }

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool PeekMessage(out Message msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint messageFilterMin, uint messageFilterMax, uint flags);

        public static ABCDE form;


        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            form = new ABCDE();

            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
            Application.Run(form);


            //udpsock2.Close();


        }

        static void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Message message;
            while (!PeekMessage(out message, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                form.UpdateFrame();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Main Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
//using DTU_BCI_SPELLER_BioRadio_Interface.FlickerTimer;

namespace DTU_BCI_SPELLER_BioRadio_Interface
{
    public partial class ABCDE : Form
    {


        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        private byte[] dataStream = new byte[1024];
        private Socket udpSock1;

        private byte[] buffer;

        public delegate void DisplayMessageDelegate(string message);
        private DisplayMessageDelegate displayMessageDelegate = null;
        public EndPoint newClientEP = null;


        private string Avalue;
        public string AVALUE
        {
            get { return Avalue; }
            set { Avalue = value; }
        }


        public ABCDE()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();
            stopwatch.Start();
            this.displayMessageDelegate = new DisplayMessageDelegate(this.DisplayMessage);
            udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);


        }

        private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket recvSock = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
                EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                int msgLen = recvSock.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
                byte[] localMsg = new byte[msgLen];
                Array.Copy(buffer, localMsg, msgLen);

                EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);

                if (msgLen > 0)
                {
                    string textToprint = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(localMsg, 0, msgLen);
                    this.Invoke(this.displayMessageDelegate, new object[] { textToprint });
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
            }

        }
        private void DisplayMessage(string messge)
        {
            int numVal;
            //SPELL.Text += messge + Environment.NewLine;

            numVal = Convert.ToInt32(messge);
            udpSock1.Close();
            if (numVal == 83)
            {

                //Application.SetSuspendState();
                BCI1 form = new BCI1();
                //Application.Run(form);
                //form.ShowDialog();
                //stopwatch.Start();
                SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + form.LET;

                udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
                buffer = new byte[1024];

                newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);

                //udpSock.Disconnect(true);
                //udpSock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            }
            else if (numVal == 76)
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                //pictureBox2.PerformClick();
                BCI2 l = new BCI2();
                l.ShowDialog();
                stopwatch.Start();
                SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + l.LET;
                udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
                buffer = new byte[1024];

                newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 70)
            {
                //pictureBox3.PerformClick();
                BCI3 l = new BCI3();
                l.ShowDialog();
                SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + l.LET;
                udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
                buffer = new byte[1024];

                newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 65)
            {
                //pictureBox4.PerformClick();
                            BCI4 l = new BCI4();
            l.ShowDialog();
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + l.LET;
            udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 61)
            {
                //pictureBox5.PerformClick();
                            BCI5 l = new BCI5();
            l.ShowDialog();
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + l.LET;
            udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 55)
            {
                //pictureBox6.PerformClick();
                            BCI6 l = new BCI6();
            l.ShowDialog();
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + l.LET;
            udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 48)
            {
                //pictureBox7.PerformClick();
                            BCI7 l = new BCI7();
            l.ShowDialog();
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + l.LET;
            udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 45)
            {
                //pictureBox8.PerformClick();
                String text = SPELL.Text;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) SPELL.Text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
                //SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text;
                udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
                buffer = new byte[1024];

                newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 40)
            {
                //pictureBox9.PerformClick();
                this.Close();
                //udpSock.Close();
            }
        }
        public void UpdateFrame()
        {
            double cycleHz1 = 0.006;

            double wave1 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz1);

            if (wave1 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz2 = 0.0065;

            double wave2 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz2);

            if (wave2 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz3 = 0.007;

            double wave3 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz3);

            if (wave3 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz4 = 0.0075;

            double wave4 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz4);

            if (wave4 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz5 = 0.0082;

            double wave5 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz5);

            if (wave5 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz6 = 0.0093;

            double wave6 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz6);

            if (wave6 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz7 = 0.010;

            double wave7 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz7);

            if (wave7 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox7.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox7.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz8 = 0.011;

            double wave8 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz8);

            if (wave8 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox8.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox8.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz9 = 0.0125;

            double wave9 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz9);

            if (wave9 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox9.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox9.BackColor = Color.White;
            }

        }
        private void ABCDE_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Threading;
//using DTU_BCI_SPELLER_BioRadio_Interface.FlickerTimer;


namespace DTU_BCI_SPELLER_BioRadio_Interface
{
    public partial class BCI1 : Form
    {


        Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        private byte[] dataStream = new byte[1024];
        private Socket udpSock2;

        private byte[] buffer;

        public delegate void DisplayMessageDelegate(string message);
        private DisplayMessageDelegate displayMessageDelegate = null;
        private string letter;
        private bool BlinkOn = false;
        public string LET
        {
            get { return letter; }
            set { letter = value; }
        }

        public BCI1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.displayMessageDelegate = new DisplayMessageDelegate(this.DisplayMessage);
            stopwatch2.Start();
            udpSock2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock2.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock2.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock2);
        }
        private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket recvSock = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
                EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                int msgLen = recvSock.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
                byte[] localMsg = new byte[msgLen];
                Array.Copy(buffer, localMsg, msgLen);

                EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                udpSock2.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock2);

                if (msgLen > 0)
                {
                    string textToprint = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(localMsg, 0, msgLen);
                    this.Invoke(this.displayMessageDelegate, new object[] { textToprint });
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
            }

        }
        public void UpdateFrame()
        {
            double cycleHz1 = 0.006;

            double wave1 = Math.Sin((stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz1);

            if (wave1 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz2 = 0.0065;

            double wave2 = Math.Sin((stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz2);

            if (wave2 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz3 = 0.007;

            double wave3 = Math.Sin((stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz3);

            if (wave3 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox3.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz4 = 0.0075;

            double wave4 = Math.Sin((stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz4);

            if (wave4 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox4.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz5 = 0.0082;

            double wave5 = Math.Sin((stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz5);

            if (wave5 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox5.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            double cycleHz6 = 0.0093;

            double wave6 = Math.Sin((stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz6);

            if (wave6 > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox6.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
        private void DisplayMessage(string messge)
        {
            int numVal;
            //SPELL.Text += messge + Environment.NewLine;

            numVal = Convert.ToInt32(messge);
            udpSock2.Close();
            if (numVal == 83)
            {

                //AB.PerformClick();
                //this.Hide();
                LET = label1.Text;
                stopwatch2.Stop();
                this.Hide();
                //udpSock.Disconnect(true);
                //udpSock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8051));
            }
            else if (numVal == 76)
            {
                //BB.PerformClick();
                LET = label2.Text;
                stopwatch2.Stop();
                this.Hide();
                //udpSock2.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 70)
            {
                //C.PerformClick();
                LET = label3.Text;
                stopwatch2.Stop();
                this.Hide();
                //udpSock2.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 65)
            {
                //D.PerformClick();
                LET = label4.Text;
                stopwatch2.Stop();
                this.Hide();
                //udpSock2.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 61)
            {
                //E.PerformClick();
                LET = label5.Text;
                stopwatch2.Stop();
                this.Hide();
                //udpSock2.Close();
            }
            else if (numVal == 55)
            {
                //button1.PerformClick();
                this.Hide();
                //udpSock2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 7 forms, which should be able to be opened and hide after selecting a character inside the form.

Comment: what happens if you un-comment the commented lines? un-comment all, except the Application.Run(form); lines - there should only be one such line - you have to show other forms elsewhere.

Comment: @JinJi, If i have as it is now, the forms open up, ut the flickering does ot happen, if i uncomment the lines, the udp connection makes the program fail.

Comment: I have now clean the code as it looks at the moment(Program.cs), with only one `Application.Run(form);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
    public static ABCDE form;
    public static BCI1 form1;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form = new ABCDE();
        form1 = new BCI1();
        form.Show();
        form1.Show();
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
        Application.Run();
    }

    static void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message message;
        while (!PeekMessage(out message, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            form.UpdateFrame();
            form1.UpdateFrame();
        }
    }
```

to set it to green:

```
long timeToBeGreenInMiliseconds = 10;
long timeWhenValue83WasSent;
bool shouldBeGreen;

void CallThisFunctionWhenValue83IsSent()
{
    timeWhenValue83WasSent = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    shouldBeGreen = true;
}

public void UpdateFrame()
{
    if( shouldBeGreen )
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        if( stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds - timeWhenValue83WasSent > timeToBeGreenInMiliseconds )
        {
            shouldBeGreen = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        double cycleHz1 = 0.006;

        double wave1 = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz1);

        if (wave1 > 0.0)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes the flickring occur. But what if I would lik to have form to be shown, and form1 only to be shown when I want it ?, the udp connection reports error because of same port number, this I had come around by closing and opening the udp along wih forms.

Comment: move "form1.Show();" to where you want it. use "form.Hide();" to hide the form. if you want to do that in other classes, you can use: Program.form1.Show(); and Program.form.Hide(); because Program is a static class

Comment: Do you a thought about how to make the BackColor green for a small period of time when a target is chosen? I am trying at the moment but it seems to be that the UpdateFrame overrule my attempt to use pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green, if the value sent by UDP is 83.@JinJi